# Best asymptotic randomized multidimensional index?

Tags: randomized-algorithms, search-trees, nearest-neighbour

What data structure has the best asymptotic running time for nearest-neighbor search on multidimensional data?  I am interested in both preprocessing time and query time, but let's restrict attention to data structures with logarithmic average query time; how low can we make the average preprocessing time?  By average, I mean the with respect to approximately uniformly distributed data.

[Kd-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) give $O(n \log n)$ average preprocessing time with $O(\log n)$ query time.  $O(\log n)$ query time is asymptotically optimal for deterministic algorithms, because $1$-nearest neighbor search can be used to solve the [element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem).  Likewise, $O(n \log n)$ preprocessing is asymptotically optimal since the kd-tree can then be used for sorting.

However, this does not prevent the existence of better *randomized* algorithms, which give the $k$ nearest neighbors with high probability.  Indeed, for approximately uniformly distributed data, there may exist deterministic algorithms that are better.

Are there any randomized algorithms for multidimensional indexing that have a better (asymptotic) preprocessing time than kd-trees while still performing log-time queries?

Comment: I think there's a similar lower bound that also applies to randomized algorithms for element distinctness, assuming comparison-based algorithms; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem#Decision_tree_complexity.  I suspect the lower bound on comparison-based sorting algorithms can also be extended to randomized algorithms as well.  So while I'm far from sure of this, I suspect the same $O(\log n)$ and $O(n \log n)$ lower bounds might apply to randomized algorithms (in the comparison-based model).